# Eliminate ASCII or / - SSH Paramiko Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

When I remote execute commands and print the output of the same, I get the path with `/` in the output:

```
\[root\@kali ~\]\
```

How do I get the output as:

```
[root@kali `]
```

Code:

```
 import paramiko
 import sys


server=ip
port=22
username=un
password=pd

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)

channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

channel.send('uname')
channel.send('\n')
channel_data = str()

channel_bytes = channel.recv(9999)
channel_data = channel_bytes.decode("utf-8")

if channel.recv_ready():
    print(channel_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace will be able to help you. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) is a link to the tutorial

```
channel_data = channel_data.replace('\\','')
```

111